# Spark 2.0 - UDF not accessible from another Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, udf

I have a problem with accessing a UDF in Spark 2.0.1. In `Task.scala` the `withColumn` calls a function from `Util.scala`. This
throws `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Char is not supported` exception, and I cannot locate where this `Char` comes from.

If I put my UDF in `Task.scala`, it works fine.

```
package main.scala

import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object Task {

      def extractDay : (String => String) = (date: String) => {
       val date_parsed : String = date.split(" ")(0)
       val formatter : DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy")
       val local : DayOfWeek = LocalDate.parse(date_parsed, formatter).getDayOfWeek()
       local.toString
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
    val col_extractDay = udf(extractDay)

      // Load LabStat Usage
      val df_usage = spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")  
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .load("data/mydata.csv")
        .toDF 

      df_usage.show()
      df_usage.printSchema()
      val df_usage2 = df_usage.withColumn("Day",   col_extractDay($"Time"))
}
}
```

But if I put `extractDay` in `Util.scala` and `import main.scala.util.Util._` suddently it throw this exception... Why?

```
package main.scala.util

import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


object Util {
          def extractDay : (String => String) = (date: String) => {
           val date_parsed : String = date.split(" ")(0)
           val formatter : DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy")
           val local : DayOfWeek = LocalDate.parse(date_parsed, formatter).getDayOfWeek()
           local.toString
        }

     val col_extractDay = udf(extractDay)
}
```

The exception message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at main.scala.Task8$.main(Task8.scala:49)
at main.scala.Task8.main(Task8.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Char is not supported
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:716)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:2837)
    at main.scala.util.Util$.<init>(Util.scala:130)
    at main.scala.util.Util$.<clinit>(Util.scala)
    ... 11 more
```